# C# - TCPListener not starting in my machine (Socket)

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server, tcplistener, netstat

Im working for a CLIENT-SERVER Application that needs to pass some DATA thru SOCKETS

Everythings working fine in my workspace (LAPTOP) and i decided to test it in other machine, And ITS NOT WORKING.

Error shows that machine actively refuse it

I've tried to check the ports running/listening using `netstat -a` in the machine and its not there.
I also try to turn OFF WINDOWS FIREWALL and configure it to allow my app to start. but still not working.

If there's someone who've encountered this type of issue,
Your help is what i need right now. Thank You!

Comment: maybe you hardcoded port numbers?

Comment: you need to get with someone that specializes in Networking LAN and WAN

Comment: A listener should be using IPAddress.Any with port number.  The only time you should get "actively refuse" with listener if another application is using the same port number which you can see in netstat.

Comment: Are you sure the port number is not already used by another process?

Comment: Are you GETTING/SWALLOWING any EXCEPTIONS? (why are we SHOUTING?)

Comment: @MrgGek - My port number is STATIC so this should be hardcoded.

Comment: @jdweng - I already stated above that i check netstat and i'm using a port that is not used.

Comment: @MatthieuCharbonnier - Yes! im sure with what i need to use and port is being used.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis - There's no Error in creating/starting TCPListener. My problem is even when my SERVER side app is actually showing no exception when running, The port that i'm using is not listed in LISTENING PORTS using NETSTAT.

Comment: ARE YOU USING IpAddress.Any?

Comment: @jdweng - Yes. There's no problem in my laptop and other machine (also in my program). My only problem is the machine that will be used as a server.

Comment: On the listener are you using IP.Any for the IP address?  Is one portal IPV4 and the other IPV6?

Comment: @jdweng - I already fixed this issue. Appreciate your help! Till next time friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fixed this problem.

IPAddress.ANY gives you all the IPAddresslist including IPV4 and IPV6. and the machine was fetching the wrong the IPAddress (IPV6).
What i did is i parse the Address list using my own checker module. And fetch only the IPV4 and set it in TCPListener.

BTW. Appreciate your help guys! Till next time.